# understanding data assigned to macros in a makefile

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have searched through this forum but am not able to find an answer to this question, still if I have missed it please excuse me and direct me to the same.

I am trying to understand makefiles and came across the makefile for the `tcpreplay` utility on Linux. There are lot of macros that have been defined with the value starting an ending in a `@`. What are these values, how are they used? A snippet:

```
    ACLOCAL = @ACLOCAL@
    AMTAR = @AMTAR@
    AR = @AR@
    AUTOCONF = @AUTOCONF@
    AUTOGEN = @AUTOGEN@
    AUTOHEADER = @AUTOHEADER@
```

Comment: These are all conventions used by the autotools build system; a search for tutorials on autotools will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a makefile template, likely for software built with a GNU `configure` script. When `configure` is run, the `@NAME@` placeholders are replaced with proper values as determined at runtime. E.g. `@AR@` will be the name (or path) of the archiver, `/usr/bin/ar`. You then have a proper `Makefile` that you can run with a `make` invokation. If an actual `Makefile` still contains `@NAME@` placeholders, there was an error in running `configure`.

You are very likely not looking at a file named `Makefile` but one named `Makefile.in`. The `.in` suffix indicating that this is input to `configure`.

You can find all the gory details in the [GNU autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Comment: Technically, they're replaced by `config.status`, which is generated at the end of `configure`. The best description of it all I've seen is adl's tutorial here: http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html